# Importing a dynamic value from an HTML form into App-Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am brand new to both HTML and App-Script. My intent here is to have a dynamic list of options from googlesheet populate a listbox in HTML and then when the user selects the value in the HTML listbox and hits the submit button, for that value to be imported back into App-Script so I can append it to another googlesheet. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() { // Retrieve values from Googlesheet and send to HTML
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");  
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  }


function update_status() { //Open the HTML Form
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('lists')
     .setWidth(200)
     .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
     .showModalDialog(html, 'Update Status');
  }


function createAgenda(form) { // Retrieve values from HTML Form
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var text = form.neworder;  //attempt to get HTML listbox value
    
  sheet.appendRow([form.neworder]);

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>  
  <div class="dropdown"></div>
  <br>
  <form>
    Select PO / Order:<br>
    <body onload="loadOrders()"></body>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" name="neworder"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" 
    onclick="google.script.run
                       .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
                       .createAgenda(this.parentNode)"/>
    </form>
       
    
</html>



<script>
  function loadOrders() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      let select = document.createElement("select");
      select.id = "select1";
      select.setAttribute("onchange", "selected()");
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").appendChild(select);
      ar.forEach(function(e, i) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;
        option.text = e;
        document.getElementById("select1").appendChild(option);
      });
    }).getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  };

  function selected() {
    const value = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    console.log(value);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`thisNode` doesn't return what you expect. It returns the `index` of the selected item, not the item itself. Also, `form` doesn't have a property `neworder`, the property is empty string `""`. I could still retrieve the selected value by going back to the sheet and the code below works. Lots of console.logs for debugging.

```
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() { // Retrieve values from Googlesheet and send to HTML
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues()));
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  }


function update_status() { //Open the HTML Form
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('lists')
     .setWidth(200)
     .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
     .showModalDialog(html, 'Update Status');
  }


function createAgenda(form) { // Retrieve values from HTML Form
  console.log(JSON.stringify(form));
  console.log(form[""]);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  //var text = form.neworder;  //attempt to get HTML listbox value
  var selected_order = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getRange(form[""]+1, 1).getValue();
  sheet.appendRow([selected_order]);

  }
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and yet, when I hit submit nothing is appended to googlesheets. Nothing happens when I click the submit button.

Comment: Make sure you have deployed a new version of your webApp otherwise your changes won’t take effect.

Comment: I did, still nothing happens when I click submit button on the HTML form.

Comment: For me, on submit, this code adds a row containing the selected cell from sheet Data to the first sheet. Isn't that what happens for you? I tested as a script only, didn't deploy as webapp. What does the execution log say when you test the script?

Comment: Ok that happens for me too.. but I don't want to select cells on the Data sheet.. I want to select values from the HTML form's listbox dropdown. http://prntscr.com/w4jvem

Comment: Here is the error.. apologies I am very new to all this so took me a while to figure out the logs. Error
Exception: The starting row of the range is too small.
    at createAgenda(Code:24:85)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation / Issue:

The server-side function `getValuesFromSpreadsheet()` returns a 2D array and your client side function that is executed by `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler` accepts `ar` which is supposed to be a 1D array of elements.

As a result the `forEach` loop does not iterate over single values but over arrays.

Assuming that everything else is working properly, you need to return a 1D array. Since you want to create a dropdown list, I assume the desired values should be also unique. Therefore I propose the following modification:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
return [...new Set(values)];
```

which uses [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert the array to 1D and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the unique values.

### Solution:

Replace the server-side `getValuesFromSpreadsheet` function with:

```
function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() { // Retrieve values from Googlesheet and send to HTML
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");  
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat();
  return [...new Set(values)];
}
```

Comment: The problem is when I try to bring it back into app-script. Getting the dynamic list is working fine. But when the submit button is clicked nothing happens.